# Nodemailer doesn't work after having previously sent emails

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have configured a sendMail function using nodeMailer and Etheral (and subsequently MailTrap).When I have sent requests to my API it worked perfectly , but now I am doing it from my front end and it just never sends the email , and neighter does it spit out any error . This is my configuration:

```
   const sendEmail=async(recipient,url,linkText)=>{
    
    
    
      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        auth: {
          user: "57438gadb0dehuwnc",
          pass: "a3cw6ge372bswtyb7"
        }
      });
    
    const message = {
      from: "Sender Name <sender@example.com>",
      to: `Recipient <${recipient}>`,
      subject: "Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔",
      text: "Hello to myself!",
      html: `<html>
        <body>
        <p>Testing SparkPost - the world's most awesomest email service!</p>
        <a href="${url}">${linkText}</a>
        </body>
        </html>`
    };
    
         transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error occurred. " + err.message);
          }
    
          console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
          // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
          console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        });
      }
```

Could you please help me understand what and why is it happening ? Thank you !

UPDATE: This is how I call the sendMail funciton:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV ==="test"){
                await sendEmail(
                    email,
                    await createConfirmEmailLink("http://localhost:8000" , supplier.id),
                    "confirm email"
                )
            }
```

Comment: it would output something, so where are you calling sendEmail?

Comment: I’m not sure if your authentication information is what you’ve actually been assigned, but if so you should be changing those details ASAP. By posting them here you’ve likely permanently entered them into the edit history of Stack Overflow as well as various search engine caches. You don’t want someone malicious using these tokens, especially when it comes to email.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have just updated the post with the call of the function, thank you so much !

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the care, but those are not the real deal!

Comment: In the browser, the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable is probably not "test". Do a `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` before the if check. It does not exist on the browser. Or even better, try commenting out the line `if (process.env.NODE_ENV ==="test"){`

Comment: @SilvanBregy I have just double checked that , it unfortunately is test.. I have checked the env variables , but the thing is that the sendMail promise never resolves ..